# How to use Styled API with typescript and props

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I am trying to styled a component (using the new styled api, not to be confused with StyleComponents).

```
const FixedWidthCell = styled(TableCell)((props: { width: number }) => ({
  width: props.width || 20,
  textAlign: "center",

}))
```

the issue is that TS complains that width is not part of the components props when using. My work around is this:

```
const FixedWidthCell = styled(TableCell)((props: { width: number }) => ({
  width: props.width || 20,
  textAlign: "center",
})) as React.ComponentType<TableCellProps & { width?: number }>;
```

But that makes me lose the typings inside the "css properties", not a big thing, but I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Could you please add a link to the documentation for the new styled API.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin here it is : 
https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#styled-component-styles-options-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use props like this:

```
const MyCard = styled(({backgroundColor, color, ...other}) => <Card {...other}/>)({
  height: '100%',
  backgroundColor: props => props.backgroundColor,
  color: props => props.color,
});
```

so for your example this should work:

```
const FixedWidthCell = styled(({width, ...other}) => <TableCell{...other}/>)({
  width: props => props.width ? props.width : 20,
  textAlign: "center",
}))
```